# In my listview Failed to convert @null into a ColorStateList

Tags: android, xml, listview

when I try implement listView in my layout I am getting this "

**Failed to convert @null into a ColorStateList**

" message in my graphical layout view. what is this? how to resolve this error?

//when I remove the list view its working/showing fine.

```
  <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/dropbox_sync_list"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </ListView>         
                <Button android:id="@+id/add_folder_dropbox"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="15dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:background="@drawable/login_blue" 
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="+ Add Folder from Dropbox"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show us the XML declaring your listview

Answer (score 0):

To your root LinearLayout add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`. Does that help?

Comment: no thats not my root. I clearly mentioned that when I remove the list view its working/showing fine.

Comment: Works for me if I copy/paste your code and remove `background` and `textColor` attributes from `ListView`.